# How can I get IDE autocomplete for PHPUnit if I installed from source?

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, phpstorm

I know it seems like a duplicate, but my problem is different:

Since I installed PHP from source, some folders are not there. I installed PHPUnit the usual way using pear.

Normally I would add `/usr/share/php` to the include path of the IDE or project and be done. But that folder doesn't exist.

```
$ updatedb
$ locate phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
/usr/local/lib/php/.channels/pear.phpunit.de.reg
/usr/local/lib/php/.channels/.alias/phpunit.txt
/usr/local/lib/php/.registry/.channel.pear.phpunit.de
/usr/local/lib/php/.registry/.channel.pear.phpunit.de/phpunit.reg

$ locate PHPUnit
/usr/local/lib/php/doc/PHPUnit
/usr/local/lib/php/doc/PHPUnit/LICENSE
/usr/local/lib/php/doc/PHPUnit/README.md
```

I tried including /usr/local/lib/php, but I still get "undefined class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase"

Note that php and phpunit work fine, I only need help with IDE autocompletion.

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe you could edit the phpunit "bin" and check where the actual PHPUnit resides?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski Good idea. I opened it and it seems like all the code is inside it, like in a huge phar file. Including it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of **PHPUnit v4** PEAR distribution now contains PHAR version instead of lots of individual files. And there is one file (`phpunit`) instead of launcher + php files (on installation `phpunit.phar` gets renamed into `phpunit`).

Because it now has no .phar extension, IDE will not be able to recognize it accordingly.

The easiest option is to download actual PHAR version of PHPUnit and place in anywhere in your project (e.g.  inside `vendors` folder).

Comment: Correct. I ended up copying bin/phunit to a tmp file, then extracted the phar with `php -r "\$phar = new Phar('/tmp/phpunit.phar');\$phar->extractTo('/tmp/phpunit');"`, and moved that directory to an included path. I did this because apparently the file was too big or something and the IDE wouldn't inspect it.

Comment: IDE inspects it just fine (the `phpunit.phar` file -- takes a bit of time though) -- tested with PHPUnit 4.0.12 in PhpStorm v8 EAP on Windows 7

Comment: It said something about being too big, I think it offered to increase the limit. But anyway the original phpunit file wasn't .phar, it had no extension. When I included it, there was no autocomplete. Maybe adding the extension would have been enough. Still it's nice to have it extracted into the original structure.

Comment: Yes -- IDE recognizes files by extensions (I have mentioned this in my answer) and you can browser content of phar file (and see individual files) from within IDE. Anyway -- it's working .. so maybe try it on next project .. or when you upgrade your PHPUnit.

Comment: Try restarting phpstorm if it doesn't recognize the phar file before starting to pull your hairs out like I did...